# 404 on HTML Form Submission to Servlet

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm using a HTML Form to send data to a servlet, the servlet then checks the data submitted is valid (against some rules) and reloads the page with new request attributes to return the results. I can almost guarantee it's not the best way of doing it but I don't think that's causing the issue. I think the issue lies in the fact the form redirects to localhost:8080/Register rather than localhost:8080/project-context/Register. Is there any way to specify the path inside the HTML? Could I do it with some JSP expressions? I'd rather not hardcode the project path as it may change in future. The HTML and relevant servlet code are below:

HTML:

```
    <body>

        <% String errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("ErrorMessage"); %>

        <form name="Register" action="/Register" method="POST">

            <%= errorMessage %><br><br>

            User name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            Verify Password: <input type="password" name="vPassword"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Verify Email: <input type="text" name="vEmail"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">

    </form>

</body>
```

Servlet/Java:

```
@WebServlet("/Register")
public class UserRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserRegistrationServlet() {

        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if (session == null) {

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/");
                return;

            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

        catch(Throwable errorMessage) {

            request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errorMessage.getMessage());
            request.setAttribute("Error Cause", errorMessage.getCause());
            request.setAttribute("ErrorLocation", this.getServletName());
            request.setAttribute("ErrorStackTrace", errorMessage.getStackTrace());

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {       

            String ErrorMessage = "";

            //Check user name is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Username") == null) {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter a username!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check user name for maximum length

            if (request.getParameter("Username").length() > 16) {

                ErrorMessage = "The username you entered was too long! Only 16 characters are allowed.";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check password is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Password") == null) {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter a password!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check password for complexity

            /*--------------------------------------------------------
            (?=.*[0-9]) a digit must occur at least once
            (?=.*[a-z]) a lower case letter must occur at least once
            (?=.*[A-Z]) an upper case letter must occur at least once
            (?=[\\S]+$) no whitespace allowed in the entire string
            .{6,16} at least 6 to 16 characters 
            ---------------------------------------------------------*/

            Pattern passwordPattern = Pattern.compile("((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z])(?=[\\S]+$).{6,16})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Matcher passwordMatcher = passwordPattern.matcher(request.getParameter("Password"));

            if (passwordMatcher.find() == false) {

                if (request.getAttribute("password") == request.getAttribute("vPassword")) {}
                else {

                    ErrorMessage = "The passwords you entered do not match!";

                    request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                    return;

                }

                ErrorMessage = "The password you entered does not abide by the strength rules!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check email is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Email") == null) {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter an email!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Validate email - *@*

            Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(request.getParameter("Email"));

            if (emailMatcher.find() == false) {

                if (request.getAttribute("email") == request.getAttribute("vEmail")) {}
                else {

                    ErrorMessage = "The emails you entered did not match!";

                    request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                    return;

                }

                ErrorMessage = "The email you entered is not valid!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            UserRegistrationBean user = new UserRegistrationBean();
            user.setUsername(request.getParameter("Username"));
            user.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
            user.setEmail(request.getParameter("Email"));

            user = UserDAO.register(user);

            if (user.getExists() == true) {

                ErrorMessage = "The user name you entered has already been registered!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

        }

        catch(Throwable errorMessage) {

            request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errorMessage.getMessage());
            request.setAttribute("Error Cause", errorMessage.getCause());
            request.setAttribute("ErrorLocation", this.getServletName());
            request.setAttribute("ErrorStackTrace", errorMessage.getStackTrace());

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you might provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to prefix [context path](http://immutant.org/documentation/0.1.0/web.html#web-context-path) before your action.

```
<form name="Register" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/Register" method="POST">
```

It is advisable to use contextPath whenever your are referring to any resources in your application.
eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/test.css"/>

<script type='text/javascript' src='${pageContext.servletContext.contxtPath}/js/test.js'></script>

<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/images/test.jpg" alt="alt text">
```

Here contextPath has been used to refer to my stylesheet, javascript and images.

[HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) ${pageContext.request.contextPath} can also be used for retrieving contextPath, however ServletContext.getContextPath() for reason specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29).

Comment: Thanks, that's the method I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="Register" action="/project-context/Register" method="POST">
```

In HTML forms you use `action` attribute of `form` element to specify the target URL.
If you want to pass the URL from a variable then put the following code in your `doGet` method:

```
request.setAttribute("actionAttr", variableWhichHoldsURL);
```

It's up to you where you define this variable. Then put this in your servlet code:

```
<% String actionAttr = (String) request.getAttribute("actionAttr"); %>
<form name="Register" action="<%= actionAttr %>" method="POST">
```

BTW. That's exactly what you do with `errorMessage` in your code.

Comment: I understand that, but is there anyway I can specify that dynamically? The project path is likely to change, multiple times.